# Text with non-breaking hyphen not aligned in tables

Tags: html, css

Something weird: when adding a non-breakable hyphen to a string in a HTML table cell, the text becomes unaligned with the other cells:

```
<table><tr><td>aligned</td><td>aligned-with normal hyphen</td></tr><tr><td>aligned</td><td>un&#8209;aligned with non breakable hyphen (&#8209;)</td></tr></table>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/1yz4mngh/2/).

Any explanation/fix for this?

Comment: Do you mean text-align? What isn't aligned?

Comment: The text in the second cell is not aligned with the text in the first cell. Only when there is a non-breakable hyphen in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical align is acting wonky.  This should fix it.

`td {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The vertical height of that character is different for some reason. If you set the vertical align it will help it look better, but it won't change the height of your content. It may be a peculiarity of the font.

https://jsfiddle.net/1yz4mngh/14/

**Html**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&#8209;</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Css**

```
td {
    background: #cccccc;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: You don't see the text in the second cell is not vertically aligned with the text in the first cell? Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Agreed, this is not the fix.

Comment: You are on the right lines. It's not so much a peculiarity of the font, but of the fact that the font used for the other characters doesn't have a glyph for the non-breaking hyphen. So the browser chooses a different font for that character, one that does contain an appropriately mapped glyph, but that font has different metrics, i.e. is taller. The td element inherits `vertical-align:middle` from its containing tbody element, so there's nothing to force it to line up, unless a different vertical alignment is chosen as in your answer.